# Showing "connecting" for a very long time while making a connection to GPU in Colab

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory

While making a connection to GPU in Google Colab, it's unable to connect and shows "connecting" for a very long time.
I have tried refreshing it and restarting the computer but none of them worked.
I was working on a deep learning project and used T4 GPU

Comment: You'll probably have a hard time getting help unless there is a known solution, as we have no way of reproducing your problem. However, if I were in your situation, I would try using a different notebook on a different computer and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by changing the runtime type from GPU to CPU and then again to GPU